# SQL Server : trigger on update value with Insert and Delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am newbie in SQL Server.

I have `Table A` with columns `id`, `name`, `delete` (boolean).

I have another `Table B` which has the same columns as A.

Once in Table A `delete` flag becomes 1 (programmatically), I need to insert that row into Table B and remove it from Table A.

So below get the results

- Table A: Has records with delete -> 0
- Table B: Has records with delete -> 1

Is it possible to achieve this via triggers?

Referring this also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Though, personally, this seems like something that should be controlled by your SPs.

Comment: `DELETE A OUTPUT deleted.whatever INTO B (columnsHere) WHERE delete = 1`

Comment: Further to @ThomA's point, why would you not just perform this in the procedure that sets the `BIT` to 1? instead of `UPDATE TableA SET delete = 1` you could `DELETE a OUTPUT DELETED.id, DELETED.name, 1 INTO TableB FROM TableA a`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can create an AFTER DELETE trigger on Table A that inserts the deleted row into Table B and removes it from Table A. Here's an example of how you can create such a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_DeleteRecord
ON TableA
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert the deleted row into Table B
    INSERT INTO TableB (id, name, delete)
    SELECT id, name, delete
    FROM deleted;

    -- Delete the row from Table A
    DELETE FROM TableA
    FROM deleted
    WHERE TableA.id = deleted.id;
END;
```

In this trigger, the `deleted` pseudo-table contains the rows deleted from Table A. You can use it to select the necessary columns and insert them into Table B. Then, you can perform a delete operation on Table A using a join with the `deleted` table to remove the corresponding rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On basis of status update from `Table A`'s `deleted` -> 0 to 1, I need to do this operation. It should be `AFTER UPDATE`??